# Where is Esperanto taught in schools?

Tags: learning

Are there any nations, cities, states, or other municipalities which allow Esperanto to be learned as a second language in their school system? Are there any notable non-public schools which do? If there are such schools, are they effective in producing Esperanto speakers?

According to the studies referenced in [this question](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/246/teaching-of-esperanto-in-schools-where-can-i-find-success-stories) teaching Esperanto in a early school setting would seem to be more beneficial than teaching another natural language, especially since the quality of instruction is often very low (as it is in my native US).

Answer (score 2):

Some universities in Hungary and Germany offer Esperanto as a foreign language.

I do not know of any such opportunities within secondary education with an explicit focus on Esperanto, however there have been [several programs using Esperanto as a propaedeutic tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaedeutic_value_of_Esperanto).

Comment: Can you give the names of said German and Hungarian Universities? Or a link to more details?

Comment: This Duolingo thread has a few interesting links, including one to a course *in* Esperanto (i.e. using Esperanto not teaching it). https://www.duolingo.com/comment/14807354/Esperanto-in-universities

Answer (score 2):

Here is some information from Spain in Esperanto:

> [...] meze de oktobro komenciĝis en la Universitato de Sevilo
>   universitata kurso “Esperanto: akademia lingvo“, kun agnosko de 6
>   kredit-poentoj, validaj por ĉiuj fakoj de la Universitato kaj kun
>   ĉeesta daŭro de 3 horoj semajne. La aktivado daŭros ĝis meze de junio
>   2018 kaj la fina celo estas faciligi la atingon de la oficiala diplomo
>   de la nivelo B1. Ĝin gvidas la profesoro Vicente Manzano-Arrondo.
>
> [...] en la Madrida Regiono, fine de oktobro komenciĝis kurso de
>   Esperanto en la Oficiala Lingvolernejo de Fuenlabrada. La aliĝo estas
>   senpaga, kaj la klasoj okazas la mardojn vespere.

Source:
[La Bitbulteno](http://www.esperanto.es/hef/component/jnews/mailing/view/listid-1/mailingid-53/listype-1?Itemid=999), NUMERO: 41 13-11-2017

Watch also: [Esperantists talk about the Sevilla students](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Oi-dKHmIz0).

[image]